# How do I design a div with a top right corner icon?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Can anyone help me to design a div with a top right corner icon?

I need the coding for this.

I herewith attached sample image for your reference.

[image: DIV WITH TOP RIGHT CORNER ICON]

Comment: SO isn't here to do your job for free, you know. What have you already tried? Add relevant code to your post.

Comment: All the users who answered this poor question should [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) - especially the "well-asked questions" section.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I see you already have answers that explain how to use relative and absolute positioning, but I created a JS fiddle in the meantime :)

[Link to JS fiddle with example](https://jsfiddle.net/vk8z6qq6/)

HTML:

```
<div id="box">
  <div id="icon">
    |&gt;
  </div>
  Contents of the box
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#box {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 100px;
  background-color: white;
}

#icon {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  top: -20px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> It will work with `css position attribute.` With refrence to the example I have made follow the below steps.

**Step 1** Give your parent `box` `positon relative`

**Step 2** Give your child element `rightCircle` `position absolute` with **right and top to adjust.**

> Basically `position :absolute` work in reference to
>   `position:relative` and with `top, right` we are adjusting the **position of the element**
>   .
>
> Here is a snippet :

```css
.box{ width:200px; height:300px; border:1px solid #999; position:relative; margin-top:30px; }
.rightCircle{ position:absolute; width:40px; height:40px; border-radius:50%;  background:red; right:-20px; top:-20px;}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="rightCircle"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
position:absolute;
right:0;
top:0;
width:{youriconimgwidth}px;
height:{youriconimgheight}px;
```

Keep in mind, before you use absolute position, the parent div should be position relative